# VBA Excel: Function to output next quarter from input date

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working in vba for excel and need the use of a function that I can input a date that is in the format of the excel converted date (such as 40736). And output the date of the quarter immediately following the input date in the format yyymmdd, where the quarters are Jan 1, Apr 1, Jul 1, and Oct 1. All calculations need to be done in vba, not in the worksheet. 
As an example: my input might be 40736 (the excel date that corresponds with 7/12/2011.
I'd like my output to be 20111001, which corresponds with the following quarter.

I'm really not sure how to even approach this so any help with strategies or proposed peices of code would be great. Thanks

Comment: Give it a try and THEN ask when you get stuck... We won't code for you - That's the way things work on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slight variation of Martin's code to give the first day of the **next** quarter:

```
Function GetQuarterDate2(InDate As Date) As Date

    Dim Quarter As Integer
    Dim OutDate As Date
    Dim yr As Long

    Quarter = DatePart("q", InDate)
    yr = Year(InDate)

    If Quarter = 1 Then
        OutDate = DateSerial(yr, 4, 1)
    ElseIf Quarter = 2 Then
        OutDate = DateSerial(yr, 7, 1)
    ElseIf Quarter = 3 Then
        OutDate = DateSerial(yr, 10, 1)
    ElseIf Quarter = 4 Then
        OutDate = DateSerial(yr + 1, 1, 1)
    End If

    GetQuarterDate2 = OutDate

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The below should work, supply your date as the InDate argument;

```
Function GetQuarterDate(InDate As Date) As Date

  Dim Quarter As Integer
  Dim OutDate As Date

  Quarter = DatePart("q",InDate)

  If Quarter = 1 Then
    OutDate = DateSerial(DatePart("yyyy",InDate),1,1)
  ElseIf Quarter = 2 Then
    OutDate = DateSerial(DatePart("yyyy",InDate),4,1)
  ElseIf Quarter = 3 Then
    OutDate = DateSerial(DatePart("yyyy",InDate),7,1)
  ElseIf Quarter = 4 Then
    OutDate = DateSerial(DatePart("yyyy",InDate),10,1)
  End If

  GetQuarterDate = OutDate

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

What the heck and why not:

```
Function GetQuarters(ByRef StartQuarter As Date) As Date
Dim DateMath As Long, EndQuarter As Date
  DateMath = DatePart("q", StartQuarter)
  EndQuarter = StartQuarter
  Select Case DateMath
    Case 1
      StartQuarter = DateSerial(Year(StartQuarter), 1, 1)
    Case 2
      StartQuarter = DateSerial(Year(StartQuarter), 4, 1)
    Case 3
      StartQuarter = DateSerial(Year(StartQuarter), 7, 1)
    Case 4
      StartQuarter = DateSerial(Year(StartQuarter), 10, 1)
  End Select
  EndQuarter = DateAdd("q", 1, StartQuarter)
  EndQuarter = DateAdd("d", -1, EndQuarter)
  GetQuarters = EndQuarter
End Function
```

Usage:

```
StartDate = (any desired date)

EndDate = GetQuarters(StartDate)
```

Fun story, came here looking for an answer to this, and then as I was about to implement this, found that I already did this.